# Constructing a formula - good coding style

Tags: r, formula

this is more a question of good coding style.

I have a piece of code that works, but I am wondering if there is a less "hacky" version that works more directly.

Here is what I am doing:

```
var_name <- 'x'  
my_formula <- paste('y ~ ', var_name)
as.formula(my_formula)
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Thanks a lot and best greetings,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reformulate`:

```r
reformulate("x", "y")
#y ~ x

reformulate(c("x", "z"), "y")
#y ~ x + z
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks better and generalizes easier!

Comment: In order to avoid scoping issues, it would often be a good idea to use the `env` parameter of `reformulate`.

Comment: Also @SebastianGerdes, I can see that you have not [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) any of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13075341/sebastian-gerdes?tab=questions) to your questions, is there a reason for this?